# I need help to iterate through multiple items with a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need help to understand for loops in JavaScript and how to iterate through multiple items.

I am building a lightbox using vanilla JavaScript based on an example that I found on Codepen here: https://codepen.io/KielBautista/pen/mxWNOb

I've altered the code to add a title and a cutline above and below the image displayed in the modal.

The titles and cutlines appear on the modal but they do not disappear when changing to the next image. The images change but the titles and cutlines just stack up.

I posted examples online and onto github to ask for help. Please look.

On Github:
https://github.com/cwebba1/Vanilla-JS_Lightbox-Slider

On Codepen:
Vanilla Responsive Lightbox
https://codepen.io/cwebba1/pen/QWjgwxe

Online are two stages of my development, before and after adding cutlines:

Before adding cutlines:

http://craigwebbart.com/prototypes/Vanilla-JS_Lightbox-Slider/Responsive_Gallery_with_Lightbox_prototype_05.html

http://craigwebbart.com/prototypes/Vanilla-JS_Lightbox-Slider/assets/js/bautista_05.js

After adding titles and cutlines

http://craigwebbart.com/prototypes/Vanilla-JS_Lightbox-Slider/Responsive_Gallery_with_Lightbox_prototype_08.html

http://craigwebbart.com/prototypes/Vanilla-JS_Lightbox-Slider/assets/js/bautista_08.js

The key area of code that I think is the problem is this portion:

```
const galleryItem = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-item");
const lightBoxContainer = document.createElement("div");
const lightBoxContent = document.createElement("div");

const lightBoxImg = document.createElement("img");
const lightBoxCutline = document.createElement("div");
const lightBoxTitle = document.createElement("div");

// . . . 

lightBoxContainer.appendChild(lightBoxContent);
lightBoxContent.appendChild(lightBoxImg);
lightBoxContent.appendChild(lightBoxPrev);
lightBoxContent.appendChild(lightBoxNext);
// These are added 021320 - hackerhurs meetup
lightBoxContent.appendChild(lightBoxTitle);
lightBoxContent.appendChild(lightBoxCutline);

document.body.appendChild(lightBoxContainer);

let index = 1;

function showLightBox(n) {
    if (n > galleryItem.length) {
        index = 1;
    } else if (n < 1) {
        index = galleryItem.length;
    }
    let imageLocation = galleryItem[index-1].children[0].getAttribute("src");
   lightBoxImg.setAttribute("src", imageLocation);
//  let alt = igalleryItem[index-1].children[0].getAttribute('alt');
  let title = galleryItem[index-1].children[0].getAttribute('title');
  if( title )
  {
    lightBoxImg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `<h4 class="title">${title}</h4>`); 
}
  let cutline = galleryItem[index-1].children[0].getAttribute('data-cutline'); //image.data.cutline;
  if( cutline )
  {
    lightBoxImg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', `<figcaption class="caption">${cutline}</figcaption>`); 
  }
}
function currentImage() {
    lightBoxContainer.style.display = "block";

    let imageIndex = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-index"));
    showLightBox(index = imageIndex);
    let titleIndex = parseInt(this.getAttribute("title"));
 console.log(this);
    lightBoxTitle(index = title);
     let cutlineIndex = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-cutline"));
   lightBoxCutline(index = cutline);
}
for (let i = 0; i < galleryItem.length; i++) {
    galleryItem[i].addEventListener("click", currentImage);
}
function slideImage(n) {
    showLightBox(index += n);
}
function prevImage() {
    slideImage(-1);
}
function nextImage() {
    slideImage(1);
}
lightBoxPrev.addEventListener("click", prevImage);
lightBoxNext.addEventListener("click", nextImage);
```

The .children[0] statement, I do not understand. Maybe that's it. How can I fix this?

Comment: `.children[0]` simply returns the first child of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to delete the existing title and caption before you add the new one in showLightBox() method. You can do this by adding below lines at the beginning of the `showLightBox()` method

With plain javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.title').forEach(function(a){
a.remove()
})
document.querySelectorAll('.caption').forEach(function(a){
a.remove()
})
```

With jQuery

```
$('.title').remove()
$('.caption').remove()
```

Be aware that this will remove all titles and captions from your dom. If you want to remove specific elements then you need to find adjacent elements specifically from `lightBoxImg` using find() method and then remove them.

Answer (score 0):

"The titles and cutlines appear on the modal but they do not disappear when changing to the next image."

what causes duplication of title and cutlines is these two lines:

```
    lightBoxImg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `<h4 class="title">${title}</h4>`); 
    lightBoxImg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', `<figcaption class="caption">${cutline}</figcaption>`);
```

to solve the problem you could change them by:

```
if( title )
  {
    lightBoxTitle.innerHTML=`<h4 class="title">${title}</h4>`; 
}
  let cutline = galleryItem[index-1].children[0].getAttribute('data-cutline'); //image.data.cutline;
  if( cutline )
  {
    lightBoxCutline.innerHTML=`<figcaption class="caption">${cutline}</figcaption>`; 
  }
```

and you've also to remove this line from (line:71) and put it in (line:67)

```
lightBoxContent.appendChild(lightBoxTitle);
```

Here is a working pen of what you are looking for:
https://codepen.io/th_/pen/dyYRYbx